# Accessing DbContext Class from Asp Mvc Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, areas

I have an admin area in my ASP.Net MVC project. I want to perform some CRUD operations in that admin area. For that I have to make some model classes. 
I have completed creating action methods and views.

Should I make the model classes in area model folder or root model folder? I have a `dbcontext` class for my code first approach in root folder. how can I make object of that `dbcontext` in admin area home controller?

How to access model classes from area to root controller and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to `dbcontext (EF_Sample)` in `controller (HomeController)` like this:

```
namespace Area_Model.Areas.admin.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /admin/Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (EF_Sample db = new EF_Sample())
            {
                var sampleList = db.Students.ToList();
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: access dbcontext]

Comment: ok.. can you please answer my this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532177/keyword-not-supported-error-in-enabling-migrations

Comment: @Abhijith Please `upvote` and `accept` this answer if it helps you, so people know this is the correct answer and helps them.

Comment: @Abhijith I see another question I hope I can help you.

Comment: if you can please help me