# Keyword not supported error in Enabling migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a dbcontext class where i have initialized 4 dbsets. My connection string is

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="somename" connectionString="Data Source=.; initial catalog=someDb; user ID=ab; Password:111111; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

My dbcotext class is

```
public AstroEntities(): base("somename")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<AstroEntities>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AstroEntities>());
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().ToTable("Contacts");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>().ToTable("Appointments");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Consultation>().ToTable("Consultations");
            modelBuilder.Entity<HomePageMessage>().ToTable("HomePageMessages");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Consultation> Consultations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<HomePageMessage> Homepagemessages { get; set; }
    }
```

When i enable automatic migrations iam getting error as follows

"Keyword not supported: 'password:111111; multipleactiveresultsets'."

Can someone say whats the problem?

Comment: Are you sure `connectionString` is correct?

Comment: not currect. password was like.. "password=" instead of "password:".. stupid careless mistakes. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Connection String` format is wrong, it should be like this

```
connectionString="Data Source=.; initial catalog=someDb; user ID=ab; Password=111111; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```